# I want to do dropbox sync in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, dropbox

I have created app in xamarin pcl. I want to do dropbox sync in ios project. I have created app in dropbox and I have app key and secret key.

I have add following mentioned code in appdelegate.cs file

```
const string DropboxSyncKey = "appKey";
const string DropboxSyncSecret = "secKey";

var manager = new DBAccountManager(DropboxSyncKey,DropboxSyncSecret);

DBAccountManager.SharedManager = manager;

var account = manager.LinkedAccount;
if (account != null) {
    var filesystem = new DBFilesystem (account);
    DBFilesystem.SharedFilesystem = filesystem;
    }
```

Now how to link user account. How user will be link to this app.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using this [Dropbox Sync & Datastore Xamarin component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/dropboxsync). From the instructions there, you should call this in a UI event handler, i.e., when the user indicates they're ready to link to Dropbox:

```
DBAccountManager.SharedManager.LinkFromController (myController)
```

There are some other setup instructions there as well.

However, this component is based on the now deprecated Sync and Datastores SDK, per [this blog post](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/04/deprecating-the-sync-and-datastore-apis/), so you probably shouldn't use it.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I want to work with xamarin pcl project. So how this will work. LinkFromController (myController).